# Abrir y envía parámetros a un activity desde una clase service

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código en el servicio:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(servicio.this, Main.class);
intent.putExtra("idVariable", "Hola mundo");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Y así lo recibo en el Main :

```
try{
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String variable = bundle.getString("idVariable");

Toast.makeText(Main.this, variable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}catch (Exception e){
System.out.println("Hooola "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Cual es el problema???

Comment: No puedo recibir los parámetros.

Answer (score 0):

El código para recepción del bundle en la clase Main debe estar dentro del método `onCreate()`, esto para recibir correctamente el valor:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...

    try{
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String variable = bundle.getString("idVariable");

    Toast.makeText(Main.this, variable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("Hooola "+e.getMessage());
    } 
    ...
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Si, el código está situado en la función onCreate.